# Can't edit all the fields in an item inside a Contao module

Tags: php, module, contao

I am having some problems with our business website that is managed with Contao.

I want to edit some fields of something, that doesn't appear on the regular edit button. To make it clear, this is what I see on the edit page:

[image: Edit page]

And this is what I see are the module details, there is a bunch of stuff that I want to change there, but can't from the actual edit page. Any way to access these options?

[image]

If I haven't made myself fully clear, please ask away.

Answer (score 0):

Contao has a detailed role configuration where every field for specific users or roles can be set. If you can't see all of the fields, it's because your user has probably not the rights to edit this fields.

You should ask the person with Contao Administration privileges if he can grant more privileges for your user or user-role.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @herr_jon, however, I am already an administrator. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not all the fields you can see in the details popup are used bei you module.

Your module type is "Course", which seems not to be from the core. So this module is from an extension.

The pallet defined in the course module is defined, to show you the fields you see, because it doesn't need more, to be configured.

Maybe aksing the maintainer of the extension, how to configure this module, is an idea.